# How to install Windows 10 from a local drive (D:) and completely wipe out the old Windows 7 System drive (C:)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, installation

I would like to install a Windows 10 from my local drive D: and completely wipe out (reformat?) my system drive C:. Is it possible at all?

- I've downloaded the .iso of Windows 10 from MSDN. I've unpacked the .iso using winrar to d:\win10*.* , so I have the directory structure in my local drive similar to a Windows 10 install DVD. (obviously boot sector not applicable)
- My current system is Windows 7 on my system drive C:.
- I have no DVD reader in my PC
- I have 2-3G free space only on my 128G system drive C:

I would like to install Windows 10, but I do not want to upgrade, neither a second Windows install, instead I would like to create a clean install.

Is it possible at all?
Is there any catch I should pay attention?

Comment: Create a bootable usb drive to install W10, [Most use Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create the bootable installer drive. Boot from the usb drive then during setup choose the partition you wish to install w10 onto.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I am not sure what you mean by `unpacked the iso to d:\win10*.*` though. You should just put the all content of the ISO directly on the target partition.

For BIOS system, the partition can be NTFS or FAT32 but needs to be the `active` partition (can be changed with `diskpart`). For UEFI system, the partition must be FAT32; boot to it through your UEFI menu.

This way you cannot change the boot mode / partition table of your system though, since you cannot `clean` the disk with `diskpart`. So if the Windows 7 was BIOS/MBR, you can only have BIOS/MBR Windows 10; if the Windows 7 was UEFI/GPT, then the Windows 10 can only be UEFI/GPT.

Comment: Regarding _"...since you cannot `clean` the disk with `diskpart`"_: Perhaps I'm reading that in the wrong way, as the way it comes across is that `diskpart` cannot clean a drive when `clean` is the command that would be given in `diskpart` to clean a drive of its partition table. I'm also perplexed by the mentioning of FAT32... the only partition in Windows that should be FAT32 is the EFI boot partition on a UEFI motherboard - all other partitions should be NTFS only, with the `active` command only being used on BIOS motherboards.

Comment: @JW0914 I think I assumed that `D:` was on the same disk as `C:`, but it is actually unclear whether it is the case of the OP. The filesystem that contains the installation files can be FAT32 or NTFS, as long as none of the files exceeds the per-file size limit.